# Связывание модели mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Может ли работать связывание модели **mvc4 asp.net**  если представление не является строго типизированным?

Создал представление строго типизированное, которое принимает коллекцию в качестве модели, но в методе действия с атрибутом `[HttpPost]` указал один параметр в виде обычного класса (элементы коллекции - это объекты этого класса).

Через необобщенные хелперы типа `HTML`.`TextBox` указал имена полей, и оно почему-то связывает данные. Хотя в двух разных книгах, написано, что для связывания данных представление должно быть строго типизированным именно тем типом, который я связываю, а не всякими коллекциями или `IEnumerable`.

Где истина все-таки?

Comment: Покажите как сигнатура контроллера выглядит, что именно он ожидает что придет и что в разметке, как хэлперы определены. Но на самом деле существует соглашение имен. Поскольку в метод контроллера все равно приходит Request и внутри MVC существует ModelBuinder, который просто по именам пришедших данных их превращает в строготипизированную коллекцию.

Comment: @polyakov_s а можно как-то поподробнее, с кодом?